# Scope of variables in JavaScript, function does not return correct value

Tags: javascript, function, scope

Good day, I've stumbled upon a trouble with scopes of variables in JS.
I have a function like this

```
var address = ...; //it may be or may not be defined earlier.
// It is not the only variable passed to the function

function search() {
    window.location.search = address;
}
```

But I need to make sure this variable in defined, so i do this

```
function search() {
    function check(value) {
        if(!value) {
            value = "1";
        }
        return value;
    }
    check(address);
    window.location.search = address;
}
```

But what I get sometimes is undefined,passed to the window.location.search, since the check() does return the "1" properly;

Can you please point out my mistake?

[UPDATE]

I should have said earlier - im just looking for a better way to do it.
Sure simple if check will get it right, but the $address variable is not the only one
You can picture it like this

```
totaladdress = address1;
totaladdress += address2;
totaladdress += address3;
totaladdress += address4;
totaladdress += address5;
...
window.location.search = totaladdress;
```

So I need a function to check them (e.g. check(address1);) and avoid several dozens of IFs to make the code cleaner.

Comment: If it may or may not be defined you need to use `typeof foo === 'undefined'`.

Comment: Did you want `window.location.search = check(address);`? You don't use the result of your `check` call anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign "1" to `value` it does not modify `address` because the String reference associated with `address` is copied into `value`, and you cannot modify the original reference. Example:

```
var address = "abc";
var value = address;
value = "def";
// address is still "abc"
```

You correctly return the string from the function, but the returned value is ignored so it doesn't help. What you want is

```
address = check(address);
window.location.search = address;
```

or just

```
window.location.search = check(address);
```

or even

```
function setAddress(value) {
    window.location.search = value || "1";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a function for this kind of check if the variable may be undefined - you need to use `typeof` directly at the place where you use the possibly undefined name:

```
function search() {
    window.location.search = typeof address !== 'undefined' ? address : 'some default value';
}
```

Comment: That is a vaild option, but the thing is - if i log the variable from within check function - it is correctly displayed as "1" if undefined. The problem is that this "1" is discarded after that and I get undefined again in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You re not returning any value from the `check` method.

```
function search() {
    function check(value) {
        if(!value) {
            value = "1";
        }
        return value;
    }
    window.location.search = check(address);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE]Sorry misunderstood what you needed. You can try this.

```
var address = ...; //it may be or may not be defined earlier.
// It is not the only variable passed to the function

function search(){
  window.address = (window.address === undefined)? 1:window.address;
  window.location.search = window.address;
}
```